# Need to increase b-modal width. VueJS.Bootsrap

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I use bootstrap v4 for VueJS and I need to increase b-modal. 
I tried different ways mentioned here : https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/632 but nothing didn't help.
In general my code looks like :

```
<b-modal :ref="fieldName" :id="fieldName" :title="msg" size="lg" modal-class="b-modal">
    <div class="script_table_container" v-if="scripts.length > 0">
      <b-table :items="scripts" per-page="10" :current-page="currentPage">
        <template slot="propertySnippet" slot-scope="data">
          <samp>
            {{data.value}}
          </samp>
        </template>
      </b-table>
      <b-pagination :total-rows="scripts.length" per-page="10" v-model="currentPage" hide-goto-end-buttons align="right"/>
    </div>

    <div slot="modal-footer">
      <b-btn class="mr-sm-2 su-btn-link" @click="close">Close</b-btn>
    </div>
  </b-modal>
```

I need to increase width up to 80-90 % of the screen cause some values inside the table are long.

Hope for your help guys. I believe you're gurus.

P.S. The answer has been found . 
To apply changes for a certain b-modals you can follow the next step :

I created globally:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
   .modal .modal-huge { 
      max-width: 90% !important;
      width: 90% !important;;
    }
 }
```

and after that I placed 'huge' into size prop of b-modal. "Huge" is used because the class ends with "huge" word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After debugging the CSS i found that you could add the following CSS rules in order to overwrite the existing ones and make the width more larger :

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
 .modal-lg {
    max-width: auto !important;
   }

@media (min-width: 576px)
  .modal-dialog {
    max-width: auto !important;

  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works but only if I can override that CSS globally. Is it possible to override it for local file ?

Comment: To override locally I made the following - I created : @media (min-width: 992px) {
  .modal .modal-huge {
    max-width: 90% !important;
    width: 90% !important;;
  }
} and after that I placed 'huge' into size prop. It works

Answer (score 23):

It isn't always practical to make new elements in your CSS file. If you want to adapt something, you always need to search where again have I defined the width, style, did I define it already, ...

I find it easier to include it directly in my code. For b-model, I found the following solution:

```
<div>
  <b-modal size="xl" title="Very large model"></b-modal>
  <b-modal size="lg" title="Large model"></b-modal>
  <b-modal size="sm" title="Small model"></b-modal>
</div>
```

It works for my version Bootstrap v4.3.

Comment: This is easier then style sheets.